# Jquery Validation on multiple Forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a html page with multiple forms. As they are dynaicmally generated sometimes there may be 1 form and sometimes there maybe 4 forms.

However I want to validate at the point of the form being submitted that each input field is populated. The code I have is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var fields = "<strong>Oops !</strong> All fields must be completed."
            $('#btn-{{ dc }}').click(function(){
                $("#error").slideToggle("slow").html(fields).hide().slideToggle( "slow" ).delay( 2200 ).slideToggle( "slow" );
                $('#????').find('input').each(function(){if($(this).val() == ""){$emptyFields.push(this)}});
                if($emptyFields.length != 0){
                    $('#{{ dc }}').find('input').css("border","");
                    $("#error").slideToggle("slow").html(fields).hide().slideToggle( "slow" ).delay( 2200 ).slideToggle( "slow" );
                  return false;
                } else {
                 return true;
                }
         });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks,

Comment: See: [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input').each(function() {
   $val = $(this).val();
   if ( value.length > 0 ) { ... }
});
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML5 validation or parsley validation (http://parsleyjs.org/).
HTML5 is a simplest way to validate forms or you can also use jquerytools ( http://jquerytools.org/ ).